# Intellij sharing project files

Tags: intellij-idea, project

We have a number (7+) of actively developed Java projects which currently use ant/ivy for build and dependency management.

All of those projects have Eclipse project files checked into the repository, so any team member can check out the source and just open the project in Eclipse.

The promblem that I am now facing is that there is no easy way to share Intellij project files (the files seem to have machine specific filepaths, etc.).

I have used Gradle in the past which has a plugin allowing to generate the Intelllij project, but no such plugin is available for Ant.

My question is, what do people usually do in such cases?

I would like to be in a position where any team member can use any IDE type (Eclipse/Intellij) without spending a lot of time setting up each and every project.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839

Comment: You can use a `build.gradle` which only generates intellij config file, and you ask intellij users to run `gradle build` when they first cloned the repo.